# How to infer resistor size from the manual of this microcontroller board?

Tags: pcb, resistors, surface-mount

I have STM32's NUCLEO-F302R8 board.  The manual is given [here](https://files.amperka.ru/datasheets/nucleo-usermanual.pdf). I couldn't find any PCB design file for this board so that I can open it in KiCad, Eagle,etc..

From the manual I couldn't figure out the resistor sizes on the bottom layer for the solder bridges SB51, SB56, SB46, SB52:

[image]

How can I infer those resistor sizes?

Comment: SB = solder bridge. It’s not a resistor. Size is “appropriate” for making a solder bridge. Do you have any pre-defined in your library?

Comment: I mean the resistor size for that solder bridge.

Comment: @winny Do you have the PCB file for this board? I couldnt find anywhere.

Comment: 0402? Normal resistor footprints comes with solderstop mask to prevent the very thing you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wouldn't use a resistor footprint for this, I would use a footprint designed to be a solder bridge. Or are you thinking of using a 0-ohm resistor for it?

Comment: Yes 0 ohm resistor for the SB

Comment: Their [cad resources page](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f302r8.html#cad-resources) has a link to the gerbers: https://www.st.com/resource/en/board_manufacturing_specification/nucleo_64pins_gerber.zip.  I didn't follow it, but that should give you footprints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CAD files that @TimWescott referenced contain the PCB layout (in the schematic zip, not necessarily where you would expect it). As typical for ST, they are in Altium.

The footprints look like this:

[image]

Outer copper dimensions are 100 mils x 40 mils. So maybe an 0805 would be appropriate.

[image]

Of course if you're doing a few by hand all you need is a soldering iron and some solder. Lead-free will work even better than nice 63/37 solder.

---

(below does not relate to your eval board)

I note that a Nucleo board I happen to have in front of me at the moment (G071RB) has jumper dimensions that are hard metric and a bit smaller (2.4mm x 1mm) and they bridge them with 0603 zero-ohm resistors. Unusually, they mask the pad off partially with solder mask (i.e. the pad is partially solder-mask defined). Probably some compromise to allow the boards to be reliably machine-assembled with zero-ohm 0603 parts- so the asymmetric pads don't pull the resistor to one side when the solder is molten and look bad or maybe even tombstone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason that first footprint you show doesn't have the soldermask opened between the pads? You would think you'd want that with a solder bridge.

Comment: @Hearth They put paste on all the pads so probably appropriate. On the second one they only put paste on the pads that were populated with 0 ohm resistors.

Answer (score 2):

A solder bridge is either a blob of solder across two specially shaped pads, or a 0-ohm resistor, also called a jumper. That's it!

The name of the thing itself tells you what to use to short it: solder :)

Comment: I actually tried this and soldering with a a blob of solder was much easier to forma bridge than using such tiny zero ohm resistors. I first tried the zero ohm resistor but failed it was super difficult to hold it tight. Finally I gave up and did solder blob between the pads.